# How to split the table with condition and join with other table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two tables:

Sales:

[image: Sales table]

Staff:

[image: [Staff table]

How can I split the Sales table by AM/PM in TYPE and join with Staff table?

The result should look like:

[image: What the final table should look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table `sales` twice, with different aliases `a` and `b`.

For example:

```
select
  s.id,
  s.name,
  a.value as am
  b.value as pm
from staff s
left join sales a on a.id = s.id and a.type = 'AM'
left join sales b on b.id = s.id and b.type = 'PM'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pivot up this table using a union and then apply the join as shown below -

---

```
Select Name,A.ID,AM,PM From
(Select ID,Value as AM, ' ' from Sales where type='AM' 
 union 
 Select ID, ' ' , Value as PM from Sales where type='PM')A
Inner Join
(select ID, Name from Staff)B ON A.ID=b.ID
```

---

Thanks